# sidekiq not obeying loop logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backgroundworker, sidekiq

I have a "perform" method for sidekiq that runs perfectly when I'm not using a worker. It looks through each page and goes through each post. If a post is older than the "since_date", everything should stop. If it isn't, it will continue until there is no more data (current_page.any?).

However, as soon as I turn on a worker to do the "perform" it doesn't obey my loop's logic to end. I initially had a break in there when my logic said to stop the loop and it worked fine. I thought maybe the "break" was causing the issue with the worker so I literally rewrote the entire function to not include "break". Turns out, it's still not obeying my logic. Here's my code:

```
begin
      current_page.each do |post|
        if Time.zone.parse(post["created_time"]) < Time.zone.at(since_date.to_i)
          continue_loop = false
        else
          process_post(post)
        end
      end
      current_page = current_page.next_page if continue_loop
    end while current_page.any? && continue_loop
```

basically this line:

```
if Time.zone.parse(post["created_time"]) < Time.zone.at(since_date.to_i)
```

when it is true, everything should stop. however, the process continues until there is no more data (when current_page.any? is false). This leads me to believe there's maybe something wrong with how sidekiq works with Time?

what am i doing wrong here?

EDIT:
I looked at the log file and it turns out sidekiq's worker thinks it's the year 1970 when doing Time.zone.at(since_date.to_i). But doing that without the worker reads the date just fine with the same value.

Comment: I think you are miss attributing the cause here but it's hard to say given the code provided. Can you show the types of your variables and where you obtain them from?

Comment: I'm getting post["created_time"] from the facebook api. since_date is coming in from a controller. here's the issue...everything works perfectly when NOT using a worker. As soon as I use a worker, something stops working properly. The only piece of logic in there that isn't obeyed it the time zone line. The worker eventually stops when the data runs out (current_page.any? is false)

Comment: Well, sounds like you need to log those times and see if there is a difference. Without being able to see the source of those values it's hard to guess where the problem might be.

Comment: dumb question but...how would I go about logging the times? I can't figure out how to get output from sidekiq. @Jonah

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Logging